# Google script app doesn't do the functions in sequence

Tags: sequence

I have 2 function in my google sheet one is to duplicate an slide template and replace some text.
I call it slidecreat.
The second one is to convert the outcome to pdf i call it converttopdf.
If I run each function separately they work fine.

If I combine them for example:

```
Functioncombine(){
 Slidcreat();
 Converttopdf();
}
```

Then convert to pdf retun a pdf file without any content that created in slidcreat.

Anyone knows what can be the problem?
I used sleep between2 function to delay between the functions thinking may slidcreat has delay to creat the slide before convert to pdf does its job but strange thing is .  output slide from slidcreat() doesnot created until the sleep time passes